# Porting code from MFC to C#

Tags: c#, interface, mfc, porting

I change some code from c++ MFC to c# and have a few questions:

1) In MFC I have a CByteArray variable.
What type should I give to this variable in c#?

2) I have a c# interface I have to use.
In MFC I connect to it with CoCreate:

```
hRet = m_pConverterImpl.CoCreate ( CLSID_Converter, IID_IConverter );
```

How should I connect to this interface from c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx): `List<byte>`. Depending on your usage, [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx) may also be suitable.
2. This is a *COM* interface. [Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285.aspx) to its DLL in your project, and VisualStudio will create a suitable C# wrapper class for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could use Activactor.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsId));

Comment: Usefull when the clsid will be variable. However, code will be ported so determine it at runtime sounds bad.